# Install Active Directory Module for Powershell without Installing RSAT?

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, powershell, windows

I would like to use the Active Directory Module for Powershell, but it seems that I first have to install RSAT, which is a rather large package. Is it possible to just install this one feature?

Answer (score 2):

No, you must install RSAT to get the Active Directory Command-Line tools.

Note that once RSAT is installed, you can choose to *only* enable the AD CLI tools if that's all you want.